# Rails format.xml render and pass multiple variables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, variables, format, render

Typical usage is:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @users }
end
```

And now I want to also pass a string named "teststring".

I've seen reference to using

```
:local => {:users => @users, :another => @another}
```

But I don't know how to merge the two together.  I just haven't seen everything all together.  Not much documentation to really explain the :xml in that line.  And I don't know if I can deal with the string with :teststring => teststring?

And lastly, how do I deal with them in my index.html.erb now that I have multiple variables?  Do they get passed with the same name from the render command?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want to render custom XML, you'll need to create a `index.xml.erb` file in the corresponding view directory for the controller. It works just like any HTML template you'd use, then:

`app/controllers/home_controller.rb`:

```
def index
    @users = ...
    @another = "Hello world!"

    # this `respond_to` block isn't necessary in this case -
    # Rails will detect the index.xml.erb file and render it
    # automatically for requests for XML
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.xml # index.xml.erb
    end
end
```

`app/views/home/index.xml.erb`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <%= @users.to_xml # serialize the @users variable %>
    <extra_string><%= @another %></extra_string>
</document>
```

(You can read about ActiveRecord's `to_xml` method [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Serialization.html#method-i-to_xml).)

Comment: The tip I got through this is that first, my string can use the @stringname nomenclature.  The second is that the variable name does get passed as the same.  Lastly, you don't seem to need all the extra info on the format.xml line, rails knows what to do.

Comment: All right, thanks for the note. I added a comment to the code based on your last point.