# Passing multiple parameter in respond_to block in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my line_items_controller in create action I have following code

```
   format.xml  { render 'carts/_cart.html.erb',
                                 :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
```

I need to send @cart as well here. I tried this

```
   format.xml  { render 'carts/_cart.html.erb', @cart,
                                 :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
```

But this is not working. Could you please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Same way as `:location`

```
format.xml  { render 'carts/_cart.html.erb', :status => :created, :location => @line_item, :cart => @cart }
```

Comment: '<% unless cart.line_items.empty? %>' This is the first line of cart partial and it gives error 'undefined local variable or method cart'

Comment: try `@cart.line_items.empty?`

Comment: @user1478137 Why you are using a html template to render xml?

Answer (score 0):

Notwithstanding you're trying to create an `xml` response with an `html` file, have you considered this:

```
format.xml  { render :partial => 'carts/cart', :status => :created, :location => @line_item }
```

> This should handle @cart in the partial, as @cart is an instance var

[Here is a more in-depth description](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to) of the `respond_to` block which you may be able to glean some nuggets from

I also found this resource for you: [Rails format.xml render and pass multiple variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5616086/rails-format-xml-render-and-pass-multiple-variables). The epic reply on there basically suggests that you define your instance variables in your function, and then use them in the `action.xml.erb` file, like this:

```
#app/controllers/home_controller.rb
def index
    @users = ...
    @another = "Hello world!"

    # this `respond_to` block isn't necessary in this case -
    # Rails will detect the index.xml.erb file and render it
    # automatically for requests for XML
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.xml # index.xml.erb
    end
end

#app/views/home/index.xml.erb
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <%= @users.to_xml # serialize the @users variable %>
    <extra_string><%= @another %></extra_string>
</document>
```

That's all I got right now